# Triangulations of the concave polygon

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, polygons, triangulation

It is known that the amount of possible triangulations of the convex polygon by disjoint diagonals is the Catalan number. But can we somehow know possible amount of the triangulations of the **concave** polygon by disjoint diagonals?

Comment: It might be better to adopt the mathematical term Simple Polygon in place of concave, as you'll find it has a precise definition..